# AWS: Code deploy installation failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, rhel, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to setup deployment from github repository via AWS.

I have an issue during these steps:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html#codedeploy-agent-operations-install-linux
```

This command fails:

```
wget https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
```

It returns:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-55 ~]$ wget https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
--2017-06-04 10:18:18--  https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
Resolving bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com (bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.114.146
Connecting to bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com (bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.114.146|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-06-04 10:18:18 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I've allowed all the ports for inbound/outbound traffic for my instance.

What is wrong?

Comment: Inbound/outbound traffic isn't the problem. `ERROR 403: Forbidden.` is the problem. Double check if you have the access to `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: @harshavmb, I don't know what it is..... I'm not sure, but it's possible that I need to replace `bucket-name` with something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, as @smart said, the "bucket-name" should be replace for different name in different region, like aws-codedeploy-us-east-2 for instances in the US East (Ohio) region etc..

Answer (score 16):

bucket-name represents one of the following:

aws-codedeploy-us-east-2 for instances in the US East (Ohio) region

aws-codedeploy-us-east-1 for instances in the US East (N. Virginia) region

aws-codedeploy-us-west-1 for instances in the US West (N. California) region

aws-codedeploy-us-west-2 for instances in the US West (Oregon) region

aws-codedeploy-ca-central-1 for instances in the Canada (Central) region

aws-codedeploy-eu-west-1 for instances in the EU (Ireland) region

aws-codedeploy-eu-west-2 for instances in the EU (London) region

aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1 for instances in the EU (Frankfurt) region

aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-1 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Tokyo) region

aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-2 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Seoul) region

aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-1 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Singapore) region

aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Sydney) region

aws-codedeploy-ap-south-1 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region

aws-codedeploy-sa-east-1 for instances in the South America (São Paulo) region

Answer (score 1):

Please check the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/resource-kit.html#resource-kit-bucket-names

to recognize *bucket-name* you have to refer to **Resource Kit Bucket Names by Region**.

Answer (score 0):

wget ***bucket-name***.s3.***region-identifier***.amazonaws.com/latest/install

> ***bucket-name*** is the name of the Amazon S3 bucket that contains the
> CodeDeploy Resource Kit files for your region. ***region-identifier*** is
> the identifier for your region.
> List of bucket names: [Resource kit bucket names by Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/resource-kit.html#resource-kit-bucket-names)

example:

```
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install
```